# In haskell, how can I interact with stdin of an `IO ()`?

Tags: haskell, testing, stdin

This shows the spirit of what I want to do and it almost works (just not within within my current nix setup):

```hs
echo :: IO ()
echo = getLine >>= putStrLn

testEcho :: IO ()
testEcho = do
  (Just stdin_hdl, Just stdout_hdl, m_stderr_hdl, p_hdl)
    <- createProcess $
         (shell ("nix run .#echo"))
           { std_in = CreatePipe
           , std_out = CreatePipe
           }
  hPutStrLn stdin_hdl "Hello, echo!"
  hClose stdin_hdl
  !response <- hGetContents stdout_hdl
  cleanupProcess (Just stdin_hdl, Just stdout_hdl, m_stderr_hdl, p_hdl)
  if response == "Hello, echo!" then
    putStrLn "Success!"
  else error "Failure"
```

basically I want something like `createProcess` but with a type of `createProcess :: IO () -> -> IO (Maybe Handle, Maybe Handle, Maybe Handle, ProcessHandle)` instead of what it actually is (`createProcess :: CreateProcess -> IO (Maybe Handle, Maybe Handle, Maybe Handle, ProcessHandle)` )

For the spirit code, you would have to make `echo` an app of your nix flake for `nix run .#echo` to work

---

What is unsatisfactory about `testEcho` is needing to use a shell command (`nix run .#echo`) when `echo` is available there as haskell code. `testEcho` also currently malfunctions within my nix environment, but works well when called from `cabal repl`.

Comment: There _is_ a library for this, though I forgot what it's called. But... it's a bit of a silly thing to do, isn't it? Why is that an `IO ()` action taking STDIN in the first place, and not just a _function_?

Comment: This echo program is quite simple, but if you had something like a program that plays tictactoe (so multiple `getLine`s) you could want to test this tictactoe program this way.

Basically I want to test/simulate a run of my program which uses stdin, and changing that program to not use stdin and just functions would be testing another program

Comment: Can you say either 1. what is unsatisfactory about the code you've posted here or 2. what behavior you want from your alternately-typed `createProcess`? I'm not sure I understand what the question actually *is* yet.

Comment: @DanielWagner hope "edit 0" makes it more specific

Comment: I've been in situations where I've needed to add tests for existing code that was written to do everything via `stdin` and `stdout`, and where refactoring it to use a given pair of handles, or use in-memory data, would have been a lot of work.

Comment: Are you saying the `echo` script you want to test is also written in Haskell, and you'd like to test a *function* that gets called during execution of the script directly, rather than having to run the script itself?

Comment: @chepner the `echo` program is only written in haskell ( `echo :: IO ()` ), and I was able to access it from a shell command thanks to nix. The question was (since it is now answered) how not to need a shell command and get stdin handle access

Comment: Don't execute it as a script; import it as a module.

Comment: Do I understand right that you have an existing `program :: IO ()` that is expecting to communicate over `stdin` and `stdout` (because it's designed to be run as a standalone program), and you want to run it from a wrapper Haskell program that will communicate with it over `stdin` and `stdout`? That desire makes sense. But if `program :: IO ()` is designed to be a standalone program it presumably would be used as the `main` of a separately compiled binary, and if you did that you could treat it exactly the same as `nix run .#echo`, couldn't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without creating another process, by redirecting `stdin` and `stdout`. This works nicely:

```hs
import Control.Exception (bracket)
import GHC.IO.Handle (hDuplicate, hDuplicateTo)
import System.Directory (getTemporaryDirectory, removeFile)
import Test.Hspec

echo :: IO ()
echo = getLine >>= putStrLn

main :: IO ()
main = hspec $ do
  specify "echo" $ do
    let line = "Hello, echo!\n"
    captureStdout (provideStdin line echo)
      `shouldReturn`
      line

provideStdin :: String -> IO a -> IO a
provideStdin input action =
  withTemporaryFile $ \h -> do
    hPutStr h input
    hSeek h AbsoluteSeek 0
    redirectStdin h action

captureStdout :: IO a -> IO String
captureStdout action =
  withTemporaryFile $ \h -> do
    redirectStdout h $ action *> hFlush stdout
    hSeek h AbsoluteSeek 0
    hGetContents' h

redirectStdin :: Handle -> IO a -> IO a
redirectStdin h action =
  bracket
    (hDuplicate stdin <* hDuplicateTo h stdin)
    (\saved -> hDuplicateTo saved stdin *> hClose saved)
    (const action)

redirectStdout :: Handle -> IO a -> IO a
redirectStdout h action =
  bracket
    (hFlush stdout *> hDuplicate stdout <* hDuplicateTo h stdout)
    (\saved -> hDuplicateTo saved stdout *> hClose saved)
    (const action)

withTemporaryFile :: (Handle -> IO a) -> IO a
withTemporaryFile inner = do
  tmp <- getTemporaryDirectory
  bracket
    (openBinaryTempFile tmp "wtf-")
    (\(name, h) -> hClose h >> removeFile name)
    (inner . snd)
```

I believe you could do several of these in a row without messing up the original `stdin` and `stdout`, but I haven't tested that.

Comment: It's also important to remember that, as it stands, this code isn't thread-safe because it manipulates global resources and doesn't use a mutex. Many test frameworks run tests in parallel, so if there are multiple tests using these functions they would interfere with each other.

Answer (score 5):

You can drop down a level to the `unix` package, which offers [`forkProcess`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.8.1.1/docs/System-Posix-Process.html#v:forkProcess). It also offers the stuff you need to set up a few fresh fds for comms. Here's a complete worked example:

```
import System.IO
import System.Posix.Process
import System.Posix.IO
import System.Posix.Types

echo :: IO ()
echo = getLine >>= putStrLn

forkWithStandardFds :: IO () -> IO (ProcessID, Handle, Handle, Handle)
forkWithStandardFds act = do
    (r0, w0) <- createPipe
    (r1, w1) <- createPipe
    (r2, w2) <- createPipe
    pid <- forkProcess $ do
        -- the six closeFd's aren't strictly speaking necessary,
        -- but they're good hygiene
        closeFd w0 >> dupTo r0 stdInput
        closeFd r1 >> dupTo w1 stdOutput
        closeFd r2 >> dupTo w2 stdError
        act
    hIn  <- closeFd r0 >> fdToHandle w0
    hOut <- closeFd w1 >> fdToHandle r1
    hErr <- closeFd w2 >> fdToHandle r2
    pure (pid, hIn, hOut, hErr)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    (pid, hIn, hOut, hErr) <- forkWithStandardFds echo
    hPutStrLn hIn "Hello, echo!"
    hFlush hIn
    response <- hGetLine hOut
    if response == "Hello, echo!" then putStrLn "Success!" else error "Failure"
    getProcessStatus True False pid >>= print
```

When run, it prints

```
Success!
Just (Exited ExitSuccess)
```

Comment: This still has the problem of needing to use an external mechanism to run the main executable, which is fragile. The code in the question will fail unless nix is installed and a flake is set up.

Comment: @NeilMayhew I don't think that's right. Just call `forkProcess echo`. No nix involved at all.

Comment: Thanks, yes, you're right. However, you still have to set up pipes to be able to read and write from the forked process.

Comment: @NeilMayhew For sure, as alluded to in the second sentence. Luckily the unix package makes it pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielWagner, for the answer. I was looking into how to pipe to stdin with what `unix` provides but stopped because Neil's answer specifies that and worked. Maybe for completeness do you have any pointers on how to do the piping?

Comment: Another point to keep in mind is that `forkProcess` comes with some major [warnings and restrictions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.8.1.1/docs/System-Posix-Process.html#v:forkProcess)

Comment: @NeilMayhew I'm not sure that your answer avoids those restrictions. The two I see are about resources shared with other threads and about the threaded runtime. Presumably accessing resources shared with other threads in the testing code would be a violation of test isolation and so a bug in the test; and as you yourself point out, your solution is not safe in the presence of multiple threads in any case.